# Semantic-UI Dropdown searches also in the 'data-value'

Tags: dropdown, semantic-ui

Is there a way that the *dropdown search* only searches in the contents?

In this example when I look for `de` it shows me *Denmark* (which I want) but also *Germany* (because of the `data-value="de"`):

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="country">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Select Country</div>
  <div class="menu">
  ...
  <div class="item" data-value="dk"><i class="dk flag"></i>Denmark</div>
  ...
  <div class="item" data-value="de"><i class="de flag"></i>Germany</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the according configuration:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
            match: "text"
        });
```